# flurry - How to flurry detect new users?

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

According to Flurry documentation,

> "New Users
>
> A new user is a user who has just started using your application.
>   Users are identified by unique phone IDs (which vary by platform) to
>   ensure that a user is in fact a unique new user and not just a
>   re-installation."

Can anyone elaborate the `"unique phone IDs (which vary by platform)"` part?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity

the device unique id is the imei number, what is different for all devices.

Comment: @Arnold : Sometimes few devices doesn't return IMEI. For example Tablets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android, the unique IDs are likely to be one of:

- Device IMEI number (only works for devices with SIM card slots)
- Bluetooth/WiFi MAC address (present on majority of devices)
- [Secure.ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) (technically present on all devices, but its known to be buggy in some versions)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do anything for it.

About how flurry does it, i'm not entirely sure but i guess they're just taking some info specific to the device and create an own 'flurry-number' out of that.

Since these info's can differ from platform (per example for Apple you could take the UDID for a long time) this 'can very by platform'.